# Show div/form after youtube finishes

Tags: youtube

I am needing to have a div hidden at first, then after the YouTube video finishes, show the div containing a form. It is for a competition that requires the user to view the video.

Cheers.

Comment: Are you using the YouTube Javascript API?

Comment: Yeah I am. At the moment I am having an issue with: player.addEventListener("onStateChange", function(state){
    if(state === 0){
    
    alert("test");

    }
});

Comment: If there is any way you can put a fiddle up, I will do my best to help you

Comment: Thanks for expressing an interest. What is a "fiddle"?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ you put the JS in one window, the HTML in another and the CSS in another.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/XyRfK/ 

At the moment, I have it to display an alert with the video finishes. But I would rather is display the div "form". Hope this makes sense. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: (Ive never worked with this API, but from the documentation, this is the best I can construct it)

```
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    alert('YT player is now on state code ' + event.data);
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
        //fire your function to show the div here.
    }
}

player.addEventListener("onStateChange", "onPlayerStateChange");
```

If this is a working solution, please remember to mark it as the answer to your question.

Also look at this. You may be missing the building blocks (since you arent directly using the api, but rather the iframe.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

Comment: cheers dude. Used the https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference and function you posted. just made a couple of edits, and it worked! Thanks again.